# Segue From Right To Left Without Push Or Presenting ViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, navigation, segue, uistoryboardsegue

Is there any possibilities to perform segue from `Right To Left` Without `push or Persenting` ViewController. The Following Code Working Fine with animation but if I use this class my `TabBar` is hidden. If I remove the code inside the `Perform()` `TabBar` is show but the animation is stop
Using `MDCBottomNavigationBar`

```
class SegueFromRight: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {
        let src = self.source
        let dst = self.destination
        src.view.superview?.insertSubview(dst.view, aboveSubview: src.view)

        dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: src.view.frame.size.width, y: 0)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,delay: 0.0,options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut,animations: {
            dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
        },completion: { finished in
            src.navigationController?.pushViewController(dst, animated: false)
        }
        )
    }
}
```

is there any other way to perform segue with animation without hiding `TabBar` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the answer. Just Removing the line `Push ViewController`

```
class SegueFromRight: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {
        let src = self.source
        let dst = self.destination
        src.view.superview?.insertSubview(dst.view, aboveSubview: src.view)

        dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: src.view.frame.size.width, y: 0)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,delay: 0.0,options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut,animations: {
            dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
        },completion: { finished in
            //Remove Following line if you want to segue modally  
            //src.navigationController?.pushViewController(dst, animated: false)
        }
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private func setupAlwaysVisibleView() {
        guard let tabBarController = self.tabBarController else { return }

        tabBarController.view.insertSubview(alwaysVisibleView, belowSubview: tabBarController.tabBar)
    }
```

Comment: I'm Using `MDCBottomNavigationBar`

Comment: insertsubview in that navigationBar ... not in views superview